# what is "works" referring to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

i have a paper  about researches that have been made about cybercrime. here is a paragraph of it

> Several **works** identify computer- and website-hacking, sabotage of networks, DoS attacks,
>   viruses and malware, spamming and phishing, digital piracy, cyber-bullying, cyberstalking,
>   internet fraud and online child pornography as different forms of cybercrime.

What does "works" mean here exactly? i know that the meaning of work as a noun is:

> 1. activity involving mental or physical effort done in order to achieve a purpose or result.
> 2. mental or physical activity as a means of earning income; employment.

but is the word "works" referring to the researches or simply jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance "works" is referring to other academic papers that have identified said actions as being different forms of cybercrime. The paper should then reference the specific papers that it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Several [literary compositions] identify computer- and website-hacking, sabotage of networks, DoS attacks, viruses and malware, spamming and phishing, digital piracy, cyber-bullying, cyberstalking, internet fraud and online child pornography as different forms of cybercrime.

As you can see, that definition of "works' also includes room for built and manufactured things. So you may come across the phrases "glass works", "art works", etc.

[image]